# Why doesn't an SSD improve performance?

Tags: 18.04, ssd, performance

I have a Dell Inspiron 5570 i7 with the following specs:

- 8GB RAM
- 256GB SSD
- 4GB Radeon graphics card
- 2TB HDD

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Still, its performance is not good and the system hangs after 2-3 applications are open. What can I do to make performance better?

[image: screenshot of the System Monitor]

Comment: You only have 8GB RAM. What are you doing exactly? What performance is not good? What exactly is the problem? Please [edit] your question to provide more details about what is wrong exactly. Having an SSD added to a system that didn't previously have one won't magically just make the system faster. If you're running applications that eat up all the RAM and send the system into swap, it will be slow no mater what. Adding more RAM is how that tends to get solved.

Comment: Can you provide examples of applications running? If it's VMWare + Android Studio (and Android Nougat Emulator), we can understand why you re hanging (due to your RAM capacity -> swap). If it just something like Terminal + Gedit + Nautilus, there is really an issue

Comment: Image attached. Increasing RAM solved the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't an SSD improve the speed of running applications?

Because running programs use RAM to run and not your disk. The only speed you see from the SSD is a quicker initial load of the software and that is just a fraction of time.

> What can I do to make performance better?

Regarding the components...

> Dell Inspiron 5570 i7

Get a better notebook. I9 will be quicker overall

> with following specs 8GB RAM

Get memory that has quicker timings. It will not make a lot of difference though.

If your system is using swap add more memory. More memory can mean a slower boot but will solve swapping. If the system uses swap it will be noticeably slower than when it does not.

Otherwise there is no speed to gain here.

> 256GB SSD, 4GB Radeon Graphic Card, 2TB HDD.

Put the OS and `/home/` on the SSD for better boot and load boot times if not done already. These have nothing to do with speeding up running programs.

> Still its performance is not good and the system hangs after 2-3 applications are open.

I do not see any proof in your question so what you are saying might be normal. 
Why not include some statistics?  Like results from `free`, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, `iostat`,  `atop`, and/or `iotop` Please add those to the question.

Comment: You're taking the "slow" claim too literally - surely the OP's laptop is perfectly capable of running "2-3 applications", it's likely some sort of misconfiguration which affects the perceived performance (e.q. the OS and the apps all still run from the HDD and the SSD does nothing). Upgrading the CPU and memory with quicker timings are not likely to make any difference, apart maybe in some benchmarks.

Comment: depends on the applications, rendering a 3d movie with blender and watching a nasa image of mars are 2 applications you do not want to do at the same time. yes over the top but hey ... ;-)

Comment: Increasing ram solved the issue. Clearly, 8Gb was not enough to support maven and angular projects. Thankyou :)

Comment: no problem. maven needs some ram indeed :) :)