# Ubuntu performance on ssd?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have been working on my own custom Ubuntu iso recently, just for the kicks of it, but one thing I have noticed is the drastically long terminal times, and it gets really slow over the course of the day.
Will switching the operating systems on the ssd and hdd fix this( windows currently is on the ssd, Ubuntu is currently on the hdd)

Just a quick question I wanted to ask.

Comment: I think lots of RAM helps Ubuntu more than fast disk speed.

Comment: I already have 12gb ram.

Comment: I think the only way to find out is to try.  This varies from person-to-person and what they are doing on the Ubuntu vs the Windows system.  Rather than ask whether switching will "fix this", you should probably ask yourself which of the two OS is your "primary" OS...  It's unlikely you will use them 50/50.  Whichever you plan to use more, you should give it the faster storage system, if size (since SSD is usually smaller than HDD) isn't a problem for you.  My Ubuntu system runs off of a HDD and it's "ok" for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response, even though I'm a little newer to Ubuntu, I find myself booting to that more then Windows now, well, I guess its time to backup that iso, and try it.

Comment: I'm not so sure this question/answer is opinion based. The objective performance enhancement of using a SSD vs a HDD is well documented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't an SSD improve performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186543/why-doesnt-an-ssd-improve-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Installing any operating system on an SSD makes a large difference in perceived speed, because operating system components and applications are loaded much faster than from a conventional HDD.

Other factors are equally important in determining the experienced speed. You need sufficient memory for all the applications you want to run at the same time, and you need an adequate processor. These three factors combined make for a overall smooth experience in different use cases. Slowness can be experiences whenever the current use causes one of these three factors to become limiting.

Comment: Here's some [basic benchmarks of HDD vs SSD on different file system types](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-416-fs&num=1) from Phoronix and [this one tested different types of drives](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-gaming-disk&num=1) (regular SATA SSD and  2 types of NVMe SSD vs HDD) for gaming.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely gonna do linux on the ssd!